# Appium (execute one more test class based on one device - not parallel)

Tags: java, xml, maven, testng, appium

I used appium v2.** (with device farm plugin)  and I have one more test class files.
this is my testng.xml file source code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >
<suite name="Test Suite Name">
<listeners>
<listener class-name="Helpers.AnnotationTransformer"/>
<listener class-name="Helpers.Listener"/>

</listeners>
<test name="some name">
<classes>
<class name="testClass1"/>
<class name="testClass2"/>
</classes>
</test>

</suite>
```

I have only one mobile device for testing.
and I execute this testng file,  appium started search 2 mobile device for execute script.
i wont to run all test file only one device  (class by class) not parallel.
how can do this? :frowning:
this problem started after appium update.
Appium starts searching for as many devices as there are test files written here

```
<class name="testClass1"/>
<class name="testClass2"/>
```

it's Base class method:

```
        public Base() throws MalformedURLException {
        DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
        capabilities.setCapability("appium:automationName", "UiAutomator2");
        capabilities.setCapability("appium:deviceName", conf.read("deviceName"));
        capabilities.setCapability("appium:udid", conf.read("udid"));
        capabilities.setCapability("appium:appPackage", conf.read("appPackage"));
        capabilities.setCapability("appium:appActivity", conf.read("appActivity"));
        capabilities.setCapability("appium:autoGrantPermissions", true);
        driver = new AndroidDriver(new URL("http://localhost:4723/wd/hub"), capabilities);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try adding the `parallel` keyword, equal to false in your test attribute.

```xml
<test name="some name" parallel="false">
```